# How to reload data in primefaces datatable from managed bean?

Tags: primefaces, datatable, reload

I want to reload data in datatable from managed bean and I thought that updating the datatable component will help:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(datatableId);
```

and will call the getttList method, that will return the updated data to the table.

This is the datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="transactionsTable" var="data" value="#{transactionsPage.ttList}" widgetVar="#{focusedTab}" 
                     rowKey="#{data.id}"
                     draggableColumns="true" 
                     draggableRows="true"
                     resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="#{msg['form.noTransactionsFound']}" rows="20"
                     selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{transactionsPage.selectedTransactions}"
                     filteredValue="#{transactionsPage.filteredttList}" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="both" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     >
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

what you posted should theoretically work

make sure to put in the correct id by checking it in the output source code of your page since primefaces is prepending the ids of parent elements to the child elements

Comment: I gave the whole path of preprended ids and checked also with Chrome DevTools and it seems correct. Is there a way to debug and see why the method getttlist(that provides data to the datatable) isn't called and check if the datatable is actually being refreshed?

Comment: Is the datatable inside ui:repeats ? on which event are you calling update ? And any reasons for invoking update from managed bean & not through xhtml ?